# how to insert uniqid() in javascript

Tags: php, uniq

I am trying to bind a **`uniqid()`** to an **`onclick`** event in a string:

```
$UniquepreID = uniqid();
$selectbutton = '<input type="button" value="testabc" 
       onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById("$UniquepreID") );" />';
```

The **`$UniquepreID`** is parsed literally. How can I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your `$UniquepreID` is within single quotes so will not be expanded. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Try this:

```
$selectbutton = '<input type="button" value="testabc" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById("' . $UniquepreID . '") );" />';
```

Comment: thanks! it works now

Answer (score 1):

Your are using single quotes to define your string variable `$selectbutton`.
You have either to use double quotes or conat your string like this:

```
$selectbutton = 'some string with "quotes"' . $uniquepreID . 'more "quotes" here';
```